# OnReadyStateComplete does not fire on IFrame

Tags: javascript, iframe, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

I have setup an IFrame on the Account Entity form in MS dynamics crm.  When the OnReadyStateComplete event fires, I do some lookups and construct a custom URL, that calls my server and returns content to be displayed in the iframe.  I used "about:blank" as the URL parameter in the setup:
[image: pic1]

Then, on the events tab, I registered the js library and the event listener - handleIFrame:
[image: 2]

Here is the content of the event handler (I removed all unnecessary code to try to get to the bottom of this).

```
function handleIFrame() {
    alert('handleIFrame');
}
```

This process is working for full version of CRM - Microsoft Dynamics® CRM Online 2015 Update
(7.0.1.247) (DB 7.0.1.237) - it displays the content in the iframe as expected.

However, in 
Microsoft Dynamics® CRM Online 2015 Update
(7.1.1.3113) (DB 7.1.1.3113) 
it seems that the OnReadyStateComplete  event does not fire at all - my alerts in the event handler do not show.  Am I correct in assuming this is a difference in versions?  Has anyone experienced anything similar? I'm new to CRM, so any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you read https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/117/t/170547

Comment: Yes, thanks - looks like he is having the same exact issue.

Comment: Did you try different browsers (IE, Chrome)?

Comment: Yes, it gives the same result in IE, Chrome and FF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After talking with Microsoft Dynamics CRM support, this is a bug in the 7.1 update.  There is a work-around, however.  In CRM, navigate to Settings > Administration > System Settings.  Then, scroll to the bottom of the popup window - here you will see:

> Use legacy form rendering - For compatibility, use the legacy form rendering engine. Note that performance may be adversely affected

Set this to "Yes" and the OnReadyStateComplete  will begin to fire.